# dynamicaly add and remove rows from table with jquery

Tags: jquery

EDIT:

ok so far i've made one of my goals to remove row... but now i can't make to recreate deletion button in previous row after current row is deleted..
code looks like this

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="header" src="images/header.png">
    <div id="content">
        <form id="survey_form" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
            <table id='survey_table' class="cols3">
                <tr>
                    <td class="row-1">1</td>
                    <td class="row-2"><input type="text" class="survey_textbox" required id="Klausimas1"/></td>
                    <td class="row-3"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="button" id="add_q" class="survey_button" value="Pridėti klausimą"/>
            <input type="submit" class="survey_button" value="Patvirtinti" style="float: right" onclick=""/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = 2;
    $("#add_q").click(function(){
        if (x <= 10){
            $("#survey_table").append("<tr id='tr"+x+"'>" +
                                        "<td class='row-1'>"+x+"</td>" +
                                        "<td class='row-2'><input type='text' class='survey_textbox' required id='Klausimas"+x+"'/></td>" +
                                        "<td id='td"+x+"' class='row-3'><input type='button' class='survey_button' value='-' id='del"+x+"'/></td>" +
                                      "</tr>");

            $("#del"+x).click(function(){
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                x--;
                $("#td"+x).append("<input type='button' class='survey_button' value='-' id='del"+x+"'/>");
            });
            $("#del"+(x-1)).remove();
            x++;
        }
    });
});
```

it looks like this line from JQuery

```
$("#td"+x).append("<input type='button' class='survey_button' value='-' id='del"+x+"'/>");
```

doesn't do the job it is supposed to do.. syntax looks good for me but i could be wrong. So maybe anyone could check where is the problem and help me out with solution? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z38t3n65/1/)**

```
     $('#container').on('click', '.survey_del', function() {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        if (x >= 2) {
            x--;
        }
        var previous = $(row).prev('tr');
        $(previous).find('td.row-3').html("<input type='button' class='survey_del' style='float: right' value='-' id='del" + x + "'>");
        $(row).remove();
    });
```

And rename the del button class to `survey_del`.

Comment: well this solution seems that it might work, but somehow after some deletions and additions it goes to negative x variable :O

Comment: It not happens to me. But you can add a condition `if (x >= 2) { x--; }` so it won't be less then 1.

Comment: i tried it with your link to fiddle, there it even duplicates delete button at some moment, but still i think i'll try to make something out from your solution cause it seems to work for me :)

Comment: sorry for interupting you, but maybe you can solve my last litle problem now? :) it looks like you understand more about jquery than i do ;D

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        var x = 1;
        $("#add_q").click(function(){
            if (x <= 10){
                $("#survey_table").append("<tr id='tr"+x+"'>" +
                "                              <td class='row-1'>"+x+"</td>" +
                "<td class='row-2'><input type='text' class='survey_textbox' required id='Klausimas"+x+"'></td>" +
                "<td class='row-3'><input type='button' class='survey_button' style='float: right' value='-' id='del"+x+"'></td>" +
                "</tr>");
                $("#del"+x).on('click', function(){console.log($(this)); $(this).parent().parent().remove()});
                x++;
            }
        });
    });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z38t3n65/

Comment: almost got it :) but there should be only one delete button on the last row of the table, and when pressed it deletes that line and creates delete button on previous row :) and x variable shoud go up or down by one depending on that :)

Comment: "delete everything in same row it is and create same delete button in previuos row." Not just delete the row. And in your example you do not decrase the x, so the ordering won't happens.

Comment: Lol.. no, it's the hungarian translation of a polish cartoon called lolek i bolek.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid multiple `parent()` calls you even could use `parents()`.

```
$("#del" + x ).click(function() {
     $(this).parents("tr").remove()
});
```

I made a jsfiddle with a test.

http://jsfiddle.net/u8gfrazu/